# How to scale up the UI of Spotify for 4K displays

Tags: snap, spotify, hdpi

The Spotify client installed from the snap store is barely usable on HiDPI displays and there seem to be no built-in options to scale the UI. Is there a workaround to scale it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is a fairly stable workaround for this. [This is discussed in the Spotify forum](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Linux-client-barely-usable-on-HiDPI-displays/td-p/1067272).

To scale the UI you can set a different scale factor at the application launch. So you want to edit the .desktop file Ubuntu uses to launch spotify to adopt a custom scale factor. As you've installed it from the snap store it will likely be located at `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/spotify_spotify.desktop`. *If not you can use find like this:* `sudo find / -type f -iname spotify.desktop`.

Then you just have to edit the `Exec` directive of this file to include the `--force-device-scale-factor=X` option, where X is the scale factor multiplier:

*Here I use `vim` for editing the file but `nano` or `gedit` can be used as well.*

```bsh
sudo vim /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/spotify_spotify.desktop
```

And then you change the `Exec` directive to include the option:

```
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/spotify_spotify.desktop /snap/bin/spotify --force-device-scale-factor=2.5 %U
```

You save the file, close Spotify, and open it again: it should be scaled properly now.

Answer (score 11):

In **recent versions** you can:

- `CTRL` + `+`: increase the size
- `CTRL` + `-`: decrease the size
- `CTRL` + `0`: reset the size

**Warning**:

> - **Don't use** `SHIFT` even if you need it, just press `+`, `-` or `0` without `SHIFT`
> - **Don't use** the **numpad** keys

Comment: This works surprisingly well.  Thanks for adding this answer.  `CTRL` + `0` to reset the zoom level as well.

Answer (score 3):

More of a hack than a solution.

Install the PWA:

1. Head to https://open.spotify.com/
2. Login to your account
3. Your browser should now present the installation of the website as a PWA (it can be discrete, in Chrome a little install icon will appear at the end of the address bar). Install it.

Since it renders in the native browser scaling, no issues with the display's pixel density.

Moreover, the PWA brings advantages over the snap version like faster startup times, better music track control integration with keyboard shortcuts, and obviously less storage if that interests you!

Comment: Indeed. Despite not solving it for the native client I've found out that Spotify's PWA is great nowadays and I've switched to it entirely. Track control with keyboard media keys works consistently now.

Comment: Note all browsers support installing PWAs. I don't think Firefox does.

Comment: I use the flatpak version.